# Mosquitto subscribe missed message from mosquitto_pub due to system acknowlegement

Tags: ubuntu, mqtt, mosquitto

I have 2 agent which are `agentA` and `agentB`, and A is trying to publish to B's broadcast channel.

With running `mosquitto_sub` on topic `agentB/broadcast`, I constantly getting the following return message:

```
Client agentB sending CONNECT
Client agentB received CONNACK
Client agentB sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: dispatcher/broadcast, QoS: 2)
Client agentB received SUBACK
Subscribed (mid: 1): 2
Client agentB sending CONNECT
Client agentB received CONNACK
Client agentB sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 2, Topic: dispatcher/broadcast, QoS: 2)
Client agentB received SUBACK
Subscribed (mid: 2): 2
Client agentB sending CONNECT
Client agentB received CONNACK
Client agentB sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 3, Topic: dispatcher/broadcast, QoS: 2)
Client agentB received SUBACK
Subscribed (mid: 3): 2
```

This sometimes will make `mosquitto_pub` "miss-fired", means my message is not published if I hit the window where system pushing the connection message.

Any solution to solve this?
Thank you.

Edit: Command to subscribe

```
mosquitto_sub -h localhost -p 8883 -v -t agentB/broadcast --cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/testing.crt -i agentA -d --cert /usr/share/agentA/config.crt --key /usr/share/agentA/config.key
```

Comment: Edit the question to include the full command line agentB

Comment: @hardillb Edited

Comment: That command is not subscribing at QOS1 or 2 so any message published while it is reconnecting will like be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the root cause. The root cause was agentA and agentB already running at the background since my system boot up. Hence when i do the manually `mosquitto_sub`, it will keep creating a new connection to that `agentB/broadcast` topic and close the old connection. This can be checked from `journalctl -fu mqtt` if you make mqtt as a service.